# Change li tag color when making new todolist

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const weather = document.querySelector(".js-weather");
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const weatherClock = document.querySelector(".clock");
const weatherGreetings = document.querySelector(".js-greetings");
const todolist = document.querySelector(".js-toDoList");
const li = todolist.querySelector("li");



function changeBlack() {
  console.log(li)
  weatherClock.classList.add("black");
  weatherGreetings.classList.add("black");
  weather.classList.add("black");
  li.classList.add('black');

}

function changeBg(imgweather) {
  const image = new Image();
  if (imgweather === "Clear") {
    image.src = `img/clear.jpg`;
    changeBlack();
  } else if (imgweather === "= Rain") {
    image.src = `img/Rain.jpg`;
  } else if (imgweather === "Clouds") {
    image.src = `img/Clouds.jpg`;
    changeBlack();
  } else if (imgweather === "Snow") {
    image.src = `img/Snow.jpg`;
    changeBlack();
  }
  image.classList.add("bgImage");
  body.prepend(image);
}

.black{
  color: black;
}
```

I want to change `li` tag color when making new li tag
so I add class black if I want to change black
but only one li tag change

when `imgweather` is Clear, I want to change all font color black because background color is white

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
const li = todolist.querySelector("li");
```

use querySelectorAll to select all list items:

```
const li = todolist.querySelectorAll("li");
```

Then you need to loop over all of your list elements inside of your changeblack() function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
  li[i].classList.add('black');
}
```

or if you prefer arrow functions:

```
li.forEach((item) => {
  item.classList.add('black');
});
```

Updated: forgot to mention querySelectorAll